# IllegalArgumentException: XXX is not part of the schema for this Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I have IllegalArgumentException each time I start my first application with Realm. My application never worked. I read a lot trying to solve my problem and I did a lot of changes.

**Android-Studio configurations:**

- Annotation enabled
- Instant run disabled

**Build.gradle config:**

- Realm version 2.2.1
- sdk version 25
- I have apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 'realm-android' 'android-apt' and 'android-command'
- I have dexOptions incremental false

**Inside my application I have**

```
Realm.init(this);
```

**I write migration code**

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if(newVersion == 0){
            oldVersion++;
        }
        if(!schema.contains("ItemCatalog")){
            schema.create("ItemCatalog")
                    .addField("id",Integer.class)
                    .addField("tab",Integer.class)
                    .addField("image", byte[].class)
                    .addField("title",String.class)
                    .addField("description",String.class)
                    .addPrimaryKey("id");
        }
    }
}
```

**Inside my first activity I have**

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().migration(new Migration())
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .name("appVenture.realm").build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

**Inside my D.T.O. object I have**

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass;

@RealmClass
public class ItemCatalog extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id = null;
    private Integer tab = null;
    private byte[] image = null;
    private String title = null;
    private String description = null;

//.. auto-generated getters and setters here
}
```

**My Big Exception is**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.francisco.helloworld, PID: 1646
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.francisco.helloworld/com.example.francisco.helloworld.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ItemCatalog is not part of the
> schema for this Realm
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2319)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ItemCatalog is not part of the schema for this Realm
> at io.realm.internal.modules.CompositeMediator.getMediator(CompositeMediator.java:172)
> at io.realm.internal.modules.CompositeMediator.getTableName(CompositeMediator.java:90)
> at io.realm.RealmSchema.getTable(RealmSchema.java:296)
> at io.realm.Realm.createObjectInternal(Realm.java:817)
> at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:801)
> at com.example.francisco.helloworld.data.RealmController$1.execute(RealmController.java:72)
> at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1253)
> at com.example.francisco.helloworld.data.RealmController.saveCatalog(RealmController.java:69)
> at com.example.francisco.helloworld.data.RealmController.saveCatalog(RealmController.java:64)
> at com.example.francisco.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5296)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What can I try next?

Comment: Did you follow the hello world tutorial? I suspect that there's a missing configuration in your application

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
apply plugin: 'realm-android' 
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'android-command'
```

You need to have

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android' 
apply plugin: 'android-command'
```

Comment: (people also seem to get this error if they have `jack { enabled true }` instead of Retrolambda as well)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today. I tried multiple solutions but they weren't working for me.

In my own case, I was already having some classes (says `RealmChild1 and RealmChild2`) which were `extending RealmObject`. The exception occured when I added a new class (`RealmChild3`) that was `extending RealmObject`. I was able to fix that by uninstalling the my app and reinstalling and launching the app again. I suspect that Realm had already create a Schema containing `RealmChild1 and RealmChild2` and it couldn't add dynamically `RealmChild3`. That is why it was complaining that `RealmChild3 is not part of the Schema for this Realm`.

Help this helps someone.

Comment: Hello @berrytchacks now on that project we use sqlLite. (that was our best solution). I solved other Realm project by reinstalling but in that project didn't work. (+1 to your comment)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's a configuration error, either with the connection and authorization setup, or with the realm objects that you've configured.

https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/

This is also related:
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3139